# How to do this on one line?

Tags: c#

I am looking at tidying up this a bit but I'm kind of new to C#

```
ResponseList responsesList = new ResponseList();
PagedResponseList pagedResponsesList = new PagedResponseList();
responsesList = responseService.ListSurveyResponses(1000);
pagedResponsesList = responsesList.ResultData;
```

This is probably an easy one, but the syntax needed to one-line this one escapes me.

Comment: are these your own custom classes?

Comment: Don't initialize variables with a new instance if you're going to overwrite them, it doesn't make sense!

Comment: Is there a reason why you must initialize `pagedResponsesList`?  If there is no particular reason, have you tried `PagedResponseList  pagedResponsesList = responseService.ListSurveyResponses(1000).ResultData`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var pagedResponsesList = responseService.ListSurveyResponses(1000).ResultData;
```

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, you don't actually need the two `new` statements in your first two lines, as those `new` instances will be overwritten by whatever you assign in your last two lines anyway.

If you're new to C#, I suggest sticking with *two lines* at minimum so you understand at least what's happening in steps. In particular, the last two lines:

```
ResponseList responsesList = responseService.ListSurveyResponses(1000);
PagedResponseList pagedResponsesList = responsesList.ResultData;
```

You can then condense those two lines into the following line if you won't be using `responsesList` later in your code, *and* you think it'll be easy to understand (basically, just chain the `.ResultData` property behind `responseService.ListSurveyResponses()`):

```
PagedResponseList pagedResponsesList = responseService.ListSurveyResponses(1000).ResultData;
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you can put it all into one line like so:

```
var pagedResponsesList = responseService.ListSurveyResponses(1000).ResultData;
```

But I think, given that you're calling off to another service, you'll really want to do some exception handling, check your result for null before referencing `.ResultData`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
PagedResponseList pagedResponsesList=responseService.ListSurveyResponses(1000).ResultData
```